# Is it possible to link lightsail servers name with ovh used by AWS servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, ovh

i've a question about NXDOMAINS of Lightsail

I've a domain registred in OVH. Also, I have an application on AWS which use this domain with Cloudfront and Route 53. So, in OVH, i've replaced Servers Name with NXDOMAIN give by AWS Route 53.

The problem is, I want to make another subdomain for my domain with an instance of Wordpress created by Lightsail, but Lightsail as is own servers name and I don't know if I need to add its servers name to OVH, and if it will create problem with redirection for my application.

I already have a redirection with the IP address of my instance to have an HTTP address, but I would like to redirect it in HTTPS

Do you have an idea ?

If you need more precision, ask me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Route53 DNS servers, you need to add the new subdomain to Route53.

When that's done, configure your application to recognize the new subdomain.